# Get only URI segments from URL

Tags: regex, url

I am trying to get the URI segments using regular expression.

Example URI:

```
http://abc.com/hello/hi/bye?humm/ok=hi&ya=yaya/wow/waaah
               ^^^^^ ^^ ^^^                    ^^^ ^^^^^
```

I am trying:

```
/(?<=\/)[\w-]+(?=(\/|$|\r|\?))/g
```

But it's not working properly. The query string is not getting excluded (`wow/waaah`).

So, when I tried the following, everything got excluded:

```
/(?<!?.+)(?<=\/)[\w-]+(?=(\/|$|\r|\?))/g
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have a look at how I fixed your post to see how to use block quotes and HTML escape codes to fix formatting problems. Don't forget to accept the best answer you receive.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't a magic wand that you wave at every programming task that involves strings. **This might not be a job for regexes**, but for existing tools in your language of choice. For example, Perl has the [URI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/) module, and PHP has the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function. Rather than writing code to interpret the URLs, use existing code that's already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape the second `?` in the second regex. It should read:

`/(?<!\?.+)(?<=\/)[\w-]+(?=(\/|$|\r|\?))/g`

Note: You could improve the regex by using character classes like so:

`/(?<!\?.+)(?<=\/)[\w-]+(?=[/\r\n?]|$)/g`

**EDIT:**

For a lowest common denominator solution to cater for all the different flavours of regex, you need a two step process:

- Remove the trailing `?` and all following chars (if it exists):

  `^[^/]+//[^/]+([^?]+)`

  Keep the string returned in capture group 1.
- Extract the URI segments by looping through:

  `/([\w-]+)`

  The segments are returned in capture group 1.

Comment: Nop, it's not working either. I am testing it at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ with "global" checked.

Comment: Tested at [RegexPlant](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) (Java)- fail. Tested with Notepad++ (PCRE) - fail (invalid regex error). Originally tested with EditPad Pro - pass.

Comment: Oops, the second regex had an error - fixed now. Seems like some regex engines don't allow some/all quantifiers in a lookbehind. PCRE doesn't allow `?` `+` `*` or `{}`. Java allows `?` and non-open ended `{}`. Got a solution now that works at [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html): `(?<!\?.{0,999})(?<=\/)[\w-]+(?=[/\r\n?]|$)`.

Comment: Humm..., so that means Regexp don't work equally every where! Algorithms differ.

Comment: @Mahesh - Ah, yeah! That's why you're asked to add a tag specifying which program/operating system you intend to run the regex on. For example, Javascript has a very poor implementation which doesn't support lookarounds at all! Did you try my new regex?

Comment: @Mahesh - Looks like we're on a winner. From the [NSRegularExpression manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html): "The length of possible strings matched by the look-behind pattern must not be unbounded (no * or + operators.)". That last regex in a previous comment should work. Let me know and I'll edit my answer to include it.

Comment: Yes i tried but no its not working. I was looking for a general solution not depending on any specific programming or os. My usages are on Java, PHP, ActionScript, VI/VIM and Linux grep command.

Comment: Look behind pattern is also not talking {0,999} but if you use i.e. {15} or {20} as a specific number it works. Seems no way we can depend on this regex. Two different regex needs to be used here. One should remove from '?' onwards and then we can proceed for the actual solution.

Comment: @Mahesh - OK. Done. Edited answer with (final?.) solution.

Comment: For extracting uri segments with `/(?<=\/)[\w-]+(?=(\/|$|\r|\n))/g` would be a better choice because `/([\w-]+)` is also selecting domain name after `//` and including a `/` also.

Comment: @Mahesh - That's because you have to extract _captured group 1_ from the first step, not the _whole match_ (just like you have to do in the second step to extract each segment). Group 1 returns `/hello/hi/bye`. You are using the entire match which is `http://abc.com/hello/hi/bye`. Your original regex used lookarounds with no capturing groups, so you could get away with using the entire match. You can't with the new versions.

Comment: But that first group is returning the whole excluding from '?'. So the 2nd group selects /abc, /hello, /hi, /bye. Here /abc should not come.

Comment: @Mahesh - What program/tool are using to test the regex?

Comment: Ok. Enter the first regex and test string. Hover over the blue highlighted bit. Read the last line of the popup. It says `group 1:/hello/hi/bye`. That is what I'm talking about. gskinner.com is a regex testing/design site. It doesn't allow you to use most of the regex features available in a _programming language_ except for simple replacement of the match. In a programming language you can assign the group 1 string to a variable and use that as the Source for the second regex. Paste `/hello/hi/bye` and the second regex into the page. Hover over each blue. Look at what comes up in group 1.